# CSS two column form Divs using current form style

Tags: css, sass

I have the following style for my form:

```
.UserForm {

  &__form {
    padding: 10px 24px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  &__form-row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    .form-field,
    .form-select,
    .textarea {
      width: 60%;
    }

    .profile-image {
       width: 60%;
    }

    .form-label {
      margin-right: 12px;
      width: 30%;
      // text-align: right;
    }

    & > .Password {
      width: 70%;
      max-width: 60%!important;
      margin: 0;
    }

  }
}
```

And this is the HTML

```
<form name="setUser" autocomplete="off" class="UserForm__form">
    <div class="form-row UserForm__form-row">
      <label class="form-label" for="firstName">First Name</label>
      <input
        v-focus
        id="firstName"
        name="firstName"
        class="form-field"
      >
      <span
        v-show="errors.has('firstName')"
        class="form-help is-danger"
      >{{ errors.first('firstName') }}</span>
    </div>

<div class="form-row UserForm__form-row">
  <label class="form-label" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
  <input
    id="lastName"
    name="lastName"
    class="form-field"
  >
  <span
    v-show="errors.has('lastName')"
    class="form-help is-danger"
  >{{ errors.first('lastName') }}</span>
</div>

</form>
```

This is how it looks like:

[image]

What I need is that **only for first name field row** I have to add other column so the text field is smaller so I can add a checkbox just to the right of the field.

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Flex" example css:

```
.UserForm__form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Flex css is great for one row manipulation.

If you are unfamiliar with flex, here is a really good resource:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp

Here is the simplified example inside snippet:

```css
.UserForm__form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<form name="setUser" autocomplete="off" class="UserForm__form">

  <div class="form-row UserForm__form-row">
    <label class="form-label" for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input v-focus id="firstName" name="firstName" class="form-field">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <label>Active</label>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: I have to keep  flex-wrap: wrap; so flex-direction: row doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably wrap the first column in another container with its own flexbox:

```
<form name="setUser" autocomplete="off" class="UserForm__form">
    <div class="form-row UserForm__form-row">
      <div class="UserForm__form-row__firstName-row">
         <label class="form-label" for="firstName">First Name</label>
         <input
           v-focus
           id="firstName"
           name="firstName"
           class="form-field"
         >
         <span
           v-show="errors.has('firstName')"
           class="form-help is-danger"
         >{{ errors.first('firstName') }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-row UserForm__form-row">
  <label class="form-label" for="lastName">Last Name</label>
  <input
    id="lastName"
    name="lastName"
    class="form-field"
  >
  <span
    v-show="errors.has('lastName')"
    class="form-help is-danger"
  >{{ errors.first('lastName') }}</span>
</div>

</form>
```

CSS:

```
.UserForm__form-row__firstName-row {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work, I have to keep the same style i have, maybe just adding extra stuff or other div

Comment: I was suggested just adding and not modifying. The additional `div` and corresponding CSS class can help distribute the space of the row evenly among the input, the error message and the checkbox

Comment: Ohh got it. Let me see

Comment: It worked but now all the row including the label and everything was moved to the right, so is not aligned to the other elments.

Comment: Can you send a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

you can try [this](https://jsfiddle.net/dsn5voLe/):

```
In yout HTML, add a label for the checkbox:

<label class="myCheckbox">
    <input type="checkbox" />
    Active
</label>

And in the SCSS, add this styles after the form-field width:

.form-field:first-of-type {
    width: 40%;
}
.myCheckbox {
    width: 20%;
}
```